# emacs23 pops up debugger way too frequently

Tags: emacs, upgrade, emacs23

Since I've upgraded to Ubuntu lucid and emacs23, Emacs pops up the debugger in situations, where emacs22 does not.

For example, when hitting C-c C-c in org-mode, emacs22 simply states `can do nothing useful at this location`, whereas in emacs23 the debugger shows up.

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "C-c C-c can do nothing useful at this location")
   signal(error ("C-c C-c can do nothing useful at this location"))
   error("C-c C-c can do nothing useful at this location")
   org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c(nil)
   call-interactively(org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c nil nil)
```

That only illustrates the pattern -- the behavior is not limited to org-mode.  Occurring every 3 minutes, it really annoys me.  How can I prevent it?

I've already tried to stop this using `debug-on-error` and `stack-trace-on-error`: it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chances are that something is setting debug-on-error after you've configured it.

Some ways to confirm:

Start Org Mode, press <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd> to enter the debugger, and <kbd>q</kbd> to exit again. Now <kbd>M-x</kbd> `set-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `debug-on-error` <kbd>RET</kbd> `nil` <kbd>RET</kbd>, and try it again.

Next, try starting emacs with the `-q` argument (to avoid executing your init file), and then entering org mode and hitting <kbd>C-c C-c</kbd>. This should not trigger the debugger.

You could use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> `debug-on-error` <kbd>RET</kbd> (or maybe `debug-on-error t`) on your site-lisp and custom lisp directories, to help track down which library is responsible.

As I could replicate your issue, I've just done this for myself. For me, the culprit was: `(load "nxhtml/autostart.el")`. I'm upgrading nxhtml now, which I suspect will resolve things in my case.

Edit: or not.

The current version of nxhtml has moved the statement from autoload.el into nxhtml-base.el. If this is the same culprit for you, you could either edit that file, or make sure that your customisation of the variable happens after nxhtml's autostart file executes.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Moving the customization statement below nxhtml has helped.

Comment: You're welcome; and thanks for asking this! I hadn't stopped to question the issue until I saw your subject line, so it's helped me out as well.