# how to switch off debug messages in emacs

Tags: emacs

I face this often. Suppose I have killed a buffer. And then I go to the "Buffer List" and try to open that buffer.

Emacs throws the error in "Backtrace" debugger window. And then I have to close this. How can I configure Emacs so that the error msgs are not shown in a separate window but in the minibuffer itself?

I am running Emacs:  23.2.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps do you have the variable `debug-on-error` set to `t`?  Try

```
(setq debug-on-error nil)
```

Comment: Sabya: Do you use nxhtml, by any chance? If so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869514/emacs23-pops-up-debugger-way-too-frequently

Comment: Yes. I am! Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 2):

As @Trey pointed out, you probably have configured Emacs to enter the debugger when an error have occurred. However, if you like this feature in general but would like to disable it for specific features you could use the variable `debug-ignored-errors`. This is a list of symbols and/or regular expressions, an error that match an entry in the list does not cause Emacs to enter the debugger.